# Monster card game anime like Yu-Gi-Oh

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember when I was a kid, I'd come home from school and watch this anime/show about this boy trying to find his missing father that dissapeared all of the sudden, leaving behind these playing cards that can summon beasts/warriors (?). The boy knew his dad would leave these cards behind as clues where he could be found, or as breadcrumbs leading to him. The premise was not unlike that of Yu-Gi-Oh, he played games that were card based, however it was distinctly different in style and monsters, I remember CGI being used.

Can anyone help me recollect what it was? I remember it frequently, however I can't seem to find it with the regular Google searches

Comment: Is there any other detail you might remember perhaps? Such as approximately when you watched it, how the cards were being used, whether it was duelling, if they summoned monsters with gadgets or magic or anything, the physical appearance of the main character (hair, age, height, eye colour, clothing), etc. Anything would help actually.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark byt the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the series is [Duel Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel_Masters).

The premise is very like Yu-Gi-Oh and the main character has a missing father and like Yu-Gi-Oh they summon monsters from cards.